# Hot and neutral touched. Some lights no longer working

Tags: light-fixture

I was disconnecting a light fixture, it slid down quickly the hot and nuetral wires touched and caused ceiling lights in three rooms to go out. One outlet is also not functioning.

I went to the panel to switch the breakers on and off.  Still no ceiling lights in three rooms.  All the outlets are working except for one.  Please advise.

Comment: You had the power on while changing a fixture?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you manipulated the breaker handle correctly? You need to turn a tripped breaker fully off before you can reset it.

If that isn't the issue, there's a weak connection somewhere in the circuit that failed due to the surge. You'll need to examine each device connection and splice for faults. Pay particular attention to "backstab" connections (rear-facing plunge clamps) on outlets and switches. They're known to fail. Use the screws with a proper wire loop instead.